# Finding directional angle theta value

Tags: python, math, angle

I have two angles (in degrees, limited to `0-359`), and I want to find the directional difference between the two angles in the direction with the smallest number needed.

For example:

1. `0, 359` would be `-1` (left `1`), and not `+359`
2. `180, 2` would be `-178` (left `178`), and not `+182`

I found some code that allows me to find the difference without the direction. How should I modify this to work directionally?

```
180 - abs(abs(old - new) - 180)
```

Comment: You probably need to use modulo 180. Or module 360 with a 180 degree shift. Something like that.

Comment: No, that piece of code already works, just not directionally.

Comment: How about `(new - old) % 360`?

Comment: Hmm, I guess that only works for left-turns. Anyway, this shouldn't be much more complicated. I don't have a piece of paper at hand.

Comment: I found the proper, simple formula once I had the pedestrian version. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first started the pedestrian way and compared the two possible rotations:

```
def nearest_signed(old, new):
    angles = ((new - old)%360, (new - old)%360 - 360)
    return min(angles, key=abs)
```

We check the modulo-360 angle, and its complement in the other direction.

It seems to work:

```
>>> nearest_signed(0, 359)
-1
>>> nearest_signed(359, 0)
1
>>> nearest_signed(180, 2)
-178
>>> nearest_signed(2, 180)
178
```

Now, I wanted to see how this behaves, so I made a plot of every angle combination:

```
import numpy as np
matplotlib.pyplot as plt                   

news,olds = np.ogrid[:360, :360]
rights = (news - olds) % 360
lefts = rights - 360
take_rights = abs(rights) < abs(lefts)
nearest_signed = np.where(take_rights, rights, lefts)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
cf = ax.contourf(news.ravel(), olds.ravel(), nearest_signed, cmap='viridis', levels=np.linspace(-180, 180, 100), vmin=-180, vmax=180)
ax.set_xlabel('new angle')
ax.set_ylabel('old angle')
cb = plt.colorbar(cf, boundaries=(-180, 180))
plt.show()
```

[image: pretty plotted result]

Now this makes it obvious that a simple modulo of the difference in angles should work. And sure enough:

```
>>> np.array_equal((news - olds + 180) % 360 - 180, nearest_signed)
True
```

Meaning that the formula you are looking for is

```
(new - old + 180) % 360 - 180
```

give or take a sign difference in your convention. If you count rotation signs the other way around, just switch the two angles:

```
(old - new + 180) % 360 - 180
```